# Angular Material Autocomplete force selection

Tags: angular, angular-material

In my angular 5 application, I have some matAutocomplete, but I want to force the selection of one of the suggestions, so I am following this approach:
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/autocomplete-force-selection-tests-w2fqww?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)
but for some reason in one case I have an issue:

> Cannot read property 'panelClosingActions' of undefined
> at CustomerDetailComponent.countryClosingActions (customer-detail.component.ts:199)
> at CustomerDetailComponent.ngAfterViewInit

I have multiple matAutocomplete but only this one have problems.
(info about this method is here [github](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3334)

**html**

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput #nation placeholder="{{'customer.detail.labels.country'
      | translate }}" required [matAutocomplete]="tdAuto" name="country"  
      #count="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="selected.country"
      (ngModelChange)="searchCountry($event)">
        <mat-autocomplete #tdAuto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
          <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="setCountry(country)" *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country">
             <div class="row">
               <img src="assets/img/flags24/{{country.alpha2Code | lowercase}}.png" />
                  <span>{{country.name}} ({{country.alpha2Code}})</span>
             </div>
         </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
```

**component**

```
@ViewChild('nation', { read: MatAutocompleteTrigger }) trigger: MatAutocompleteTrigger;
  subscription: Subscription;


ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.countryClosingActions();
  }

  private countryClosingActions(): void {
    if (this.subscription && !this.subscription.closed) {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    this.subscription = this.trigger.panelClosingActions
      .subscribe(e => {
        console.log('closing')
        if (!e || !e.source) {
          this.selected.country = null;
          this.selfCountry = null;
        }
      },
      err => this.countryClosingActions(),
      () => this.countryClosingActions());
  }
```

Comment: Maybe this could be helpful https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3334

Answer (score 23):

Using blur event and matAutocomplete output event (optionSelected) we can force user to select option.

```html
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Country*" matInput formControlName="country" [matAutocomplete]="countryAutoList" (blur)="checkCountry()">
  <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #countryAutoList="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="countryClick($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of countryList" [value]="item.Name">{{item.Name}}</mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

ts file functions

```js
countryClick(event: any) {
  this.selectedCountry = event.option.value;
}

checkCountry() {
 setTimeout(()=> {
  if (!this.selectedCountry || this.selectedCountry !== this.signatureFormGroup.controls['country'].value) {
    this.signatureFormGroup.controls['country'].setValue(null);
    this.selectedCountry = '';
  }
 }, 1000);
}
```

depend on your requirement you can always delay the function which you call in blur or optionSelect event using setTimeout window function.

```
setTimeout(()=> { 
// function contents
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Blur event called First

Comment: @anonymous So, what is the solution? Any idea?

Comment: @jonathan You can use setTimeout in any function to delay it.

Comment: @Amitkumar Could you update your answer by including setTimeout so that people can use this approch without any problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @jonathan Done :)

Comment: @Amitkumar Thanks a lot, voted up. I am not sure if `.setValue(null)` remove all of the elements from list.

Answer (score 5):

From Angular Material 16.2.1, you can use the requireSelection directive on mat-autocomplete:

This in the template:

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <mat-label>Number</mat-label>
    <input #input
           type="text"
           placeholder="Pick one"
           matInput
           [formControl]="myControl"
           [matAutocomplete]="auto"
           (input)="filter()"
           (focus)="filter()">
    <mat-autocomplete requireSelection #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions" [value]="option">
        {{option}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

And this in the class:

```
@ViewChild('input') input: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;
  myControl = new FormControl('');
  options: string[] = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five'];
  filteredOptions: string[];

  constructor() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.options.slice();
  }

  filter(): void {
    const filterValue = this.input.nativeElement.value.toLowerCase();
    this.filteredOptions = this.options.filter(o => o.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
  }
```

Docs: [Angular Material - Autocomplete - Require an option to be selected](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview#require-an-option-to-be-selected)

Answer (score 4):

I found [this](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3334) helpful:

```
private subscribeToClosingActions(): void {
if (this.subscription && !this.subscription.closed) {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}

this.subscription = this.autoCompleteTrigger.panelClosingActions
  .subscribe((e) => {
      if (!e || !e.source) {
        const selected = this.matAutocomplete.options
          .map(option => option.value)
          .find(option => option === this.formControl.value);

        if (selected == null) {
          this.formControl.setValue(null);
        }
      }
    },
    err => this.subscribeToClosingActions(),
    () => this.subscribeToClosingActions());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The example they give on the site uses Reactive Form approach, but in your case you seem to lean toward Template Driven Approach, but you're not using a form period.

So you could directly access the dom element like you're doing now.

Create a local reference to your input, maybe call it autoComplInput

Inside your component file, you'll want to import `ElementRef` and View `Child`

```
import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
```

Inside your component, import ViewChild, and declare it an ElementRef type

```
@ViewChild('autoComplInput') autoComplInput: ElementRef;
```

Then at some point of initialization, just assign referenced element value

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.autoComplInput.nativeElement.value = this.countries[0];
  }
```

---

Demo based on Angular Material 2's example, since you didn't provide all the information needed.

In your html

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput
         placeholder="{{'country'}}"
         required
         [matAutocomplete]="tdAuto"
         name="country"
         #autoComplInput
         (ngModelChange)="searchCountry($event)">
  <mat-autocomplete #tdAuto="matAutocomplete" >
    <mat-option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country">
      <div class="row">
        <span>{{country}} </span>
      </div>
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

In your component

```
import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: '<...>',
  templateUrl: '<...>',
  styleUrls: ['<...>'],
})
export class <...> implements OnInit  {

  @ViewChild('autoComplInput') autoComplInput: ElementRef;

  countries = [
    'Alabama',
    'Alaska',
    'Arizona',
    'Arkansas',
    'California',
    'Colorado',
    'Connecticut',
    'Delaware',
    'Florida',
    'Georgia',
    'Hawaii',
    'Idaho',
    'Illinois',
    'Indiana',
    'Iowa',
    'Kansas',
    'Kentucky',
    'Louisiana',
    'Maine',
    'Maryland',
    'Massachusetts',
    'Michigan',
    'Minnesota',
    'Mississippi',
    'Missouri',
    'Montana',
    'Nebraska',
    'Nevada',
    'New Hampshire',
    'New Jersey',
    'New Mexico',
    'New York',
    'North Carolina',
    'North Dakota',
    'Ohio',
    'Oklahoma',
    'Oregon',
    'Pennsylvania',
    'Rhode Island',
    'South Carolina',
    'South Dakota',
    'Tennessee',
    'Texas',
    'Utah',
    'Vermont',
    'Virginia',
    'Washington',
    'West Virginia',
    'Wisconsin',
    'Wyoming',
  ];
  constructor( ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.autoComplInput.nativeElement.value = this.countries[0];
  }


}
```

Comment: I have to unset the valu on panelclosing action, so I need `@ViewChild('nation', { read: MatAutocompleteTrigger }) trigger: MatAutocompleteTrigger;`

Answer (score 1):

You can Create custom Validator , this will validate it perfectly tested code:

```
stateCtrl = new FormControl(null,[forbiddenNamesValidator(this.states)])


export function forbiddenNamesValidator(States: any[]): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
    const index = States.findIndex(State=> {
      return (new RegExp('\^' + State.name + '\$')).test(control.value);
    });
    return index < 0 ? { 'forbiddenNames': { value: control.value } } : null;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe I'm late, but I fount this https://onthecode.co.uk/force-selection-angular-material-autocomplete/
Really simple solution based on validator:

```
export function RequireMatch(control: AbstractControl) {
    const selection: any = control.value;
    if (typeof selection === 'string') {
        return { incorrect: true };
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This solution work only if you don't attempt a string value.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following method:

[Angular Material Autocomplete Component Force Selection: Complete Example](https://onthecode.co.uk/force-selection-angular-material-autocomplete/)

Here is the demo on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-force-selection-autocomplete-component)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and I solved it with a custom directive. Here is the code I used on matautocomplete https://v14.material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples#autocomplete-display:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[requireSelection]',
})
export class RequireSelectionDirective {
  @Input('requireSelection') matAutoComplete!: MatAutocomplete;
  constructor(private ngControl: NgControl) {}

  @HostListener('blur')
  onBlur() {
    const value = this.ngControl.control?.value;
    const matchingOptions = this.matAutoComplete.options.find(
      (option) => JSON.stringify(option.value) == JSON.stringify(value)
    );
    if (!matchingOptions) {
      this.ngControl.control?.setValue(null);
      this.ngControl.control?.setErrors({ selectionRequired: true });
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <mat-form-field floatLabel="always">
    <mat-label>Assignee</mat-label>
    <input
      type="text"
      matInput
      [formControl]="myControl"
      [matAutocomplete]="auto"
      [requireSelection]="auto"
      [required]="true"
    />
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
      <mat-option
        *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async"
        [value]="option"
      >
        {{option.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
    <mat-error *ngIf="myControl.hasError('selectionRequired')">
      Please select a valid option
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Comment: does not work when you search and select it clear selected one.