# Angular Material Autocomplete force selection not working

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material

Tring to make an autocomplete with angular material that force the user to choosed from the autocomplete.
i've followed this topic but its not seems to work:

[Angular Material Autocomplete force selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48419050/angular-material-autocomplete-force-selection)

i tried the approach with adding a blur to the input and optionSelected.
But its seems that the blur event always fire before my optionSelect so optionSeleced never get fire.

```html
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <div formGroupName="CityGroup">
    <input (blur)="checkCity()" #autoComplInput type="text" placeholder="city" aria-label="Number" required matInput
      formControlName="cityName" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option (click)="optionSelect(option,$event)" *ngFor="let option of filteredOptionsCity | async" [id]='0'
        [value]="option.cityName">
        {{option.cityName}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </div>
<mat-form-field>
```

TS

```js
checkCity() {
    if (!this.selectedCity.cityName || 
    this.selectedCity.cityName !== this.form.get('CityGroup').get('cityName').value) {
        this.form.get('CityGroup').get('cityName').setValue('');
        this.selectedCity = '';
}
```

Comment: Can u add a demo code of stackblitz

Comment: What do you mean by `force the user to choosed from the autocomplet`?

Comment: Could be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/48419050/12292636.  
Please note that since Angular 16.2 there is a new property [requireSelection](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api) which might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

You could subscribe to valueChanges from FormControl and check if it's valid. On blur you could check if it's valid or not and clear it. Something like this:

HTML

```
<form class="example-form">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input (blur)="blurInput()" type="text" placeholder="Pick one"
            aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
                {{option}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

TS

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  myControl = new FormControl();
  options: string[] = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
  isValid = false;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myControl.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
      let results = this.options.filter(option => {
        return option.toLowerCase().startsWith(val.toLowerCase());
      });
      this.isValid = results.length > 0;
    });
  }

  blurInput() {
    if (!this.isValid)
      this.myControl.setValue("");
  }
}
```

Or maybe add a custom validator: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55375942